# Existence of a partial ordering that makes two elements comparable

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

Let $X$ be a set, $x',y'$ elements of $X$ and let $P$ be the set of all partial orderings of $X$; is it true that there exists $\leq \in P$ such that either $x\leq y$ or $y\leq x$ (or both)? i.e. is is true that there must be some partial ordering of $X$ such that $x$ and $y$ can be compared? Why is that so?

(Note: I'm aware of the fact that if we assume the well-ordering principle the answer is yes, I'm wondering if the same is true if we do not assume it)

Best regards,

lorenzo.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila : I'm not asking specifically if there exists a total order, I want to know: if $x',y'$ are two elements in a set $X$ is there a partial ordering $\leq $ of $X$ such that $x',y'$ can be compared? (even if with this ordering $\leq$ there are $x'', y''\in X$ which cannot be compared, but which by this same reasoning could be compared with another ordering $\leq '$).

Comment: (1) That is not indicative from your question; (2) take the order in which $x$ is below $y$, and any other $z$ cannot be compared to any element.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila : Understood, thank you for your answer.